# When editing a presentation in powerpoint, is there any way to scroll continuously between the slides?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, scrolling, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, scroll-wheel

Pretty much the title. I don't like the way that a single scroll wheel 'notch' moves an entire slide. I would rather scroll continuously between slides if possible.

Maybe I'm wrong and it would be more annoying that way, but I'd like to try it if I can.

Comment: When you select any slide from the left pane (slide previews), you can use your mouse wheel to scroll between your slides.

Comment: Yes, I realise that, but each discrete movement of the scroll wheel moves an entire slide. I would like each movement to just move me slightly downwards, as if I were scrolling through multiple pages of a document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand what you want; if it's just for viewing, you could convert the presentation to PDF and get a continuous scroll effect by changing your Reader settings.

View | Page Display | Enable Scrolling

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 2):

Continuous scroll works in Slide sorter view. Just zoom in slides as much as you want.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't let you zoom more than 200%, making it impossible to have less than 2 slides side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a transition between two slides. Try a 'Push from bottom' transition with slow transition speed and you will get a scroll effect, though you wont have a control of scroll as you want like in a pdf file.